# UITableView set contentInset with swipe action is overlapping

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm having UI issue on UIKit as attached image below.

I want to have a trailing padding 16 pixels from egde for cell, but the sectionIndexTitles must always be there (so I don't use trailing constraint in this case). But after I set the contentInset, the problem with the swipe action is that it is calculated from the edge and not from the position where I inset inside.

I setup tableView as follow (I also don't know why when set inset for right it doesn't work, but when set to left, it has right padding):

```
private func setupUI() {
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: -16.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
    tableView.adjustedContentInsetDidChange()
}
```

Does anyone know how to align it?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use contentInset? you can give spacing with constraints

Comment: Because I want the sectionIndexTitles always be there. If I use constraint, it moves along.